# Cannot connect to Ryuk

Tags: java, testcontainers

As far as i know, ryuk serves as the main independent resource handler container for other testcontainers.

I have observed unexpected behavior during the execution of integration tests in both the local environment and Jenkins using a Postgres testcontainer. Occasionally (though infrequently), I encounter the following warning message:

```
WARN org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:32769 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

followed by this error

```
07:59:16.503 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Timed out waiting for Ryuk container to start. Ryuk's logs:
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Pinging Docker...
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Docker daemon is available!
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Starting on port 8080...
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Started!
```

Once the Docker service is restarted or Ryuk is disabled, the situation returns to normal. Alternatively, the issue may resolve itself after several attempts.

I have read several threads such as

```
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3609

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4954

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-17236

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/581
```

However, I have not identified any specific reasons explaining this behavior. Also i am a bit confused with the provided discussions, answers and closed threads without any specific solution point.

Testcontainers version is 1.15.1.
Error occured on ubuntu 20.04 and Amazon linux.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? If so, what was determined to be the cause? Additionally, are there any alternatives to Ryuk for resource reaping purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your "ryuk issue" is not directly related to `testcontainers` functionality, however there is a room for improvement, at least for linux hosts, the reasoning is following:

your log

```
07:59:16.503 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Timed out waiting for Ryuk container to start. Ryuk's logs:
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Pinging Docker...
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Docker daemon is available!
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Starting on port 8080...
2023/06/09 11:58:46 Started!
```

reveals following:

- `ryuk` container got started
- `ResourceReaper` has been trying to reach it during 30 seconds and failed

under "normal conditions" ryuk `v0.3.0` logs should look like:

```
2023/06/10 15:15:45 Pinging Docker...
2023/06/10 15:15:45 Docker daemon is available!
2023/06/10 15:15:45 Starting on port 8080...
2023/06/10 15:15:45 Started!
2023/06/10 15:15:48 Connected
```

i.e. `ryuk` container typically logs information about clients connected (last line in my listing), but your log does not contain such information, which in turn could mean following:

- operating system (or java) was to busy to schedule execution of [spawned thread](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/1.15.1/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/utility/ResourceReaper.java#L157)
- logging engine or `ResourceReaper` is broken in testcontainers `v1.15.1` and it does not log enough diagnostic information (anyway, `1.15.1` version is definitely too old and it is better off updating testcontainers first)
- there is some network connectivity issue caused by one of the following: overlapping networks, firewall setup, ephemeral port ranges, issues in docker engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe it's nothing of these 3 [overlapping networks, firewall setup, ephemeral port ranges]. I mean i have checked all of them locally based on the threads i mentioned, and they seem fine. I am not sure about the jenkins env. But locally they are ok. ill try to update the docker engine and testcontainers version.

Comment: both your logs and logs provided in mentioned github issues lack lines about connected clients. btw, on CI side we do not use `ryuk`, instead we are doing something like: `Jenkins` creates dedicated network with name like `${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}` and passes that name to maven via system property, java code creates containers taking into account that network name, upon completion `Jenkins` removes all containers attached to the network and the network itself, moreover, since `Jenkins` is running on `Linux` we do not use docker's port mapper on CI side.

Comment: Atm i am running a separate container on jenkins which handles the mvn install. I am a bit worried about the logs. Example : 

ERROR org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper - Timed out waiting for Ryuk container to start. Ryuk's logs:
2023/06/07 07:51:10 Pinging Docker...
2023/06/07 07:51:10 Docker daemon is available!
2023/06/07 07:51:10 Starting on port 8080...
2023/06/07 07:51:10 Started!

It says that was timed out while waiting for ryuk container to start. but ryuk logs emphasizes "started". Probably a misleading log ? it should say connected also ?

Comment: `ResourceReaper` logs are bit misleading: `Started!` in `ryuk` container log means container has been started and it has discovered docker engine via unix socket, `Timed out waiting for Ryuk container to start` in testcontainers log means testcontainers has failed to connect to `ryuk` container via TCP, the absence of `Connected` line in `ryuk` container log means it has not seen any incoming connections - that is a connectivity issue between java, `ryuk` container and docker engine in the middle.

Comment: try to run `ryuk` container manually, i.e. `docker run -p 8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.0`, than connect to it's mapped port, i.e. `nc localhost XXXX` and check `ryuk` container logs - it prints `Started` upon TCP connection has been established.

Comment: I tried to update the version on the latest one but the problem still occurs, more often when the jenkins is overloaded. I think ill just disable ryuk and follow the manual approach as proposed here https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/ with an @Afterall cleanup method addition. Also the whole process of the mvn install takes place in a separate container in the jenkins environment, which is deleted after the job is done.

Comment: `mvn install takes place in a separate container` - that changes a lot, in that case, I believe, you are using something like https://java.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/, and most probable testcontainers fails to discover docker host (I believe it should not be `localhost` as in your logs). Does setting env variable `TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE` to real docker host change behaviour?

Comment: To be more specific is a separate pod. and the container inside the pod has -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock configured. So i think this is fine. At least it works on 90% of the cases without heavy load.